# Rails ActiveJob - how to stop job from being enqueued in before_enqueue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I am running Rails 4.2.8 and I want to make my job only run under certain conditions.  Currently I am doing that check in the code that is calling the job but it would be much cleaner to contain the logic in the job class.  Has anyone done that?

```
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  before_enqueue do |job|
    # check and stop job from being enqueued under certain conditions
  end
  def perform(args*)
    # code here
  end
end
```

I am using Sidekiq 4.2.10 as the background job adapter.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`around_enqueue`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cfb1e4dfd8813d3d5c75a15a750b3c53eebdea65/activejob/lib/active_job/callbacks.rb#L133) to achieve the same result without raising the exception. This can be useful when not enqueuing is something to be expected by your job.

Ex:

```
around_enqueue do |_job, block|
   if my_condition 
      block.call # this will enqueue your job
   end
end
```

OBS: Worth noting that this answer is based on Rails 5 ActiveJob code but must work on Rails 4 as well.

Comment: I think using around_enqueue is the only option to cancel job before adding it to the queue. I tried using before_enqueue in combination with discard_on, but it didn't work. The exception was not catched and it was stopping execution of the code in the process that was enqueueing the job.

Answer (score 1):

`throw :abort` from your `before_enqueue` to halt the execution of the callback chain and `perform`.

Code: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc20050ea69ba3b8d8bc90171d2dcbf93e9a1dae/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L23

Comment: I tried raising exception in `before_enqueue` and using `discard_on` but it didn't work. The exception was not catched and it was stopping execution of the code. So your solution does not work @Sergio. Raising exception and discarding will work if exception is raised in before_perform callback. It is maybe because before_enqueue is run in the same process that enqueued the job, but the before_perform is run in sidekiq worker.

Comment: The tests in the Rails repository seem to indicate that by `throw`-ing an `exception` (not to be confused in Ruby with `raise`-ing an `error`) `:abort` it would stop the enqueuing of the job. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/291a3d2ef29a3842d1156ada7526f4ee60dd2b59/activejob/test/cases/callbacks_test.rb#L154

Comment: @Adeynack `:abort` is not an exception, though

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: In Ruby terms, it is. Exceptions are symbols. See https://coderwall.com/p/lhkkug/don-t-confuse-ruby-s-throw-statement-with-raise

Comment: @Adeynack: no, and no. Exceptions are exceptions and symbols are symbols. In ruby we use "[raise an exception](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Exception.html)" and "raise an error" interchangeably. Not sure what you wanted to say with this post, because it does not back up your claim.

Comment: @Adeynack: thanks for pointing this out, though. This stuff clearly changed since 2014 :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: It got me very confused at first, but `throw` in Ruby is not used for error management, but for interrupting code flows, as the article explains. `catch(:miracle_of_miracles) do ... end` is the beginning of that flow. A method down the stack, called inside that `do...end` block will `throw :miracle_of_miracles`, and Ruby will bubble that up. In the end, it's a similar behavior; but not the same semantic. Does it make more sense in those words?

Comment: As of for changes in the language, @SergioTulentsev, I wouldn't. I started with Ruby in 2019, so for me, lots of +/- "new language features" were just "there" when I learned it.

Comment: @Adeynack: yep, that sounds more like it. :+1: